# How to create organizational contact using MS Graph or Office 365 REST API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Office 365 administration center allows to create **organizational** contacts which are shared with all users in organization.

In MS Graph documentation API of this functionality is badly documented and located in BETA section. Moreover, there is no command to create such a contact: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/orgcontact

It looks like in Graph this functionality was not implemented. Using typical POST request to the /beta/contacts ends with an error response in Json structure: `Unsupported resource type 'Contact' for operation 'Create'.`

Note 1: I don't have any user logged in. My application uses service/daemon authentication.

Is there any other way to create **organizational** contact?

Answer (score 4):

At this time, creating new [orgContact](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/orgcontact) objects isn't supported by the Graph API. You also cannot create organizational contacts with the [Azure AD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/contacts-operations). For more information about organizational contacts, including how they are created in your tenant, see the [Contact Entity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#contact-entity) documentation.

[Organization Contacts](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/orgcontact) are documented in the [beta section](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/beta-overview) because this API is in fact still in beta. I'm sorry you ran into issues here but with any beta endpoint there is always likelihood of missing/broken features and sparse documentation. There is also a substantial likelihood of breaking changes being rolled out to beta endpoints. As such, we do not recommend using them in production scenarios.

Comment: So the only way to create organizational contact from external program is to create it in directory on the local machine and then sync local directory with Azure AD?

Comment: Is there any roadmap when this feature became available?

Comment: Given that most of the CRUD functions are already supported, it seems reasonable to expect creation to become available at some point. I do not have an ETA however.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT Where can we post a enhancement request to have the REST api allowing creation of contacts? (Having update/delete but NOT create is not realy usefull) And only having powershell is no good for automation

Comment: There is a [User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) for Office and Graph (and yes, it is actively read and acted on by the product teams). This one is already requested but could always use more votes: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/17617309-make-it-possible-to-create-organizational-contacts

Comment: We are almost in 2022 and we don't have this feature in Graph API. So Odd.

Comment: 2023 checking in: still not a feature in Graph API